# Use SignalR CLIENT in web API server project

Tags: signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

Server 1 pushes event data to Server 2 (via SignalR).
Server 2 takes the event data and saves it to SQL.

Server 2 also hosts a Blazor Server project to provide the DbContext/API for a Blazor WebAssembly project intended to display the SQL data and real-time events.

In this scenario, Server 2 has to be both a SignalR client and server (for the WebAssembly project)

On Server two, should I have 3 projects?

1. SignalR client
2. Blazor Server
3. Blazor WebAssembly

Or two projects

1. Blazor Server + SignalR client
2. Blazor WebAssembly

I can't figure out how to configure a Blazor Server project (.Net 6) to also subscribe to events from Server 1.  Should I use a BackgroundWorker? Or setup a separate project for the SignalR client (subscribed to server 1)?

Comment: To further clarify:

[ Event publisher ] --> [ Blazor Server --> Blazor WebAssembly ]

Should I create a generic host in the Blazor Server program.cs?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-tutorial-build-blazor-server-chat-app) about building a chat app. Maybe it helps you.

According to this example BlazorHub does this job.

```
namespace BlazorChat
{
    public class BlazorChatSampleHub : Hub
    {
        public const string HubUrl = "/chat";

        public async Task Broadcast(string username, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("Broadcast", username, message);
        }

        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Context.ConnectionId} connected");
            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Disconnected {e?.Message} {Context.ConnectionId}");
            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And here SignalR client [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=server)

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@implements IAsyncDisposable

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        User:
        <input @bind="userInput" />
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        Message:
        <input @bind="messageInput" size="50" />
    </label>
</div>
<button @onclick="Send" disabled="@(!IsConnected)">Send</button>

<hr>

<ul id="messagesList">
    @foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        <li>@message</li>
    }
</ul>

@code {
    private HubConnection? hubConnection;
    private List<string> messages = new List<string>();
    private string? userInput;
    private string? messageInput;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/chathub"))
            .Build();

        hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
        {
            var encodedMsg = $"{user}: {message}";
            messages.Add(encodedMsg);
            StateHasChanged();
        });

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }

    private async Task Send()
    {
        if (hubConnection is not null)
        {
            await hubConnection.SendAsync("SendMessage", userInput, messageInput);
        }
    }

    public bool IsConnected =>
        hubConnection?.State == HubConnectionState.Connected;

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (hubConnection is not null)
        {
            await hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My question is how to set up a SignalR CLIENT in a Blaser SERVER project for .Net 6

Comment: I've added client example too from MS document.